# Spring Security SwitchUserFilter exitUserUrl ignored?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I'm having a problem with spring security's `SwitchUserFilter`. When I login with the ADMIN role I can switch user and back again. The problem is that when switching user for the second time I can't seem to switch back. When I go to /secured/switch/back directly in the browser this shows in my logs.

```
[FilterChainProxy] : /secured/admin at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
...
[AbstractSecurityInterceptor] : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /secured/admin; Attributes: [hasRole('ADMIN')]
[AbstractSecurityInterceptor] : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@99f3cebe: Principal: harry [OTHER]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 756CEC9064C2B1B4D788624786F26137; Granted Authorities: OTHER, Switch User Authority [ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR,org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6b846d6c: Principal: max [ADMIN]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 26B09EEF635C1758BE96B86AB6354434; Granted Authorities: ADMIN]
[AffirmativeBased] : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3e35ec54, returned: -1
[ExceptionTranslationFilter] : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

Normally when a user switches back using the configured `/secured/switch/back` url the `FilterChainProxy` starts to filter a request for url **/secured/switch/back**. However, the second time the url changes to **/secured/admin** and permission is denied.

Does someone has a clue what might be going on here?

I have the following configuration.

```
<beans:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">

    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="org.example.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/secured/admin/switch/user" />
    <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/secured/switch/back" />
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="successHandler" ref="RedirectingAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.example.RedirectingAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/secured/access/denied" >
    <custom-filter ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/login/auth" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/switch/back" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'OTHER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/other/**" access="hasRole('OTHER')" />

    <form-login
            login-page='/secured/login'
            login-processing-url="/secured/login/auth"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            />

    <logout logout-url="/secured/logout" logout-success-url="/secured/login" />
```

and success handler

```
public class RedirectingAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedirectingAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);

    private static final RoleBasedRedirectStrategy redirectHandler = new RoleBasedRedirectStrategy();

    /*
     *  Redirect request based on user role.
     *
     *  For example:
     *      Role ADMIN redirects to /secured/admin
     *      Role OTHER redirects to /secured/other
     */
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        logger.info("Authentication successful for {}", user);
        redirectHandler.handleRedirect(request, response, user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `redirectHandler` **is not** sending permanent redirects (301)?

Comment: @PavelHoral You're a champ! It **did** send a 301 redirect. Changing it to 302 (FOUND) made it work. I don't fully understand why it happened only on the second time a user switches back though. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Permanent redirects can be cached by clients. So there was no actual second request to `/secured/switch/back` and it goes directly to previously resolved success URL => *access denied* as you were still logged as `OTHER`.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for clarifying that. Could you make that into an answer so I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: Done... thank you for acceppting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extracted from the question comments:*

> Are you sure your `redirectHandler` **is not** sending permanent redirects (301)?

Permanent redirects can be cached by clients. So there might be no actual second request to `/secured/switch/back` and it goes directly to previously resolved success URL `/secured/admin` (and that would cause *access denied* (403) as you are still logged as `OTHER`).

By the way there is [method for sending temporary (302) redirects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) (used also by Spring's [DefaultRedirectStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultRedirectStrategy.java#L39)):

```
response.sendRedirect(targetUrl);
```